# jQuery Content Panel Switcher vs. Slidesjs slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using these two plugins on my website: jQuery Content Panel Switcher and Slidesjs slider. Content Panel slider switching the content after click link, but in one of these contents I need to use Slidesjs slider. It works after page load, but when a user changes the content, slidesjs disappears. I am not sure this is a good description, come here and see a live preview: [live preview](http://jsbin.com/ozikec/3/edit).

Try to click on photography for example and the click back to the homepage.

Comment: I've done all I can, there doesn't appear to be a method in which to use these two together; this is because the panel switcher erases all inline css that the slider creates, and the slider does not have a destroy method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content switcher is breaking the slidesjs because it alters the dom structure. You should not use the switcher in this use case. Instead:

- set all views except the first to `display:none`.
- when clicking a link, do a jQuery `fadeOut()` on the current view.
- make a `setTimeout`, wait for the `fadeOut` to complete, then `fadeIn()` to the element you want to display

Comment: Interesting solution, though it could be improved upon.

Comment: Unfortunately I need combination of these, the project is little bit complicated, hard to explain... I would have to recode whole project and there is no time so I am trying to find qucik solution.

Comment: @user2289373 You can either use different plugins and accept the fact that there is no way the two can be used together, or hack into each plugin to modify them so they can work together.  One solution is far less intensive than the other.